# How to apply regular expression for Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, bdd

I am trying to get message log from Azure application Insight like this

```
az monitor app-insights --app [app id] --analystics-query [condition like specific message id]
```

Then I got a message like this

> "message": [
> "Receiving message: {"type":"CTL","traceId":"f0d11b3dbf27b8fc57ac0e40c4ed9e48","spanId":"a5508acb0926fb1a","id":{"global":"GLkELDUjcRpP4srUt9yngY","caller":null,"local":"GLkELDUisjnGrSK5wKybht"},"eventVersion":"format version","timeStamp":"2021-10-01T14:55:59.8168722+07:00","eventMetadata":{"deleteTimeStamp":null,"ttlSeconds":null,"isFcra":null,"isDppa":true,"isCCPA":true,"globalProductId":null,"globalSubProductId":null,"mbsiProductId":null},"eventBody":{"sys":"otel","msg":"Testing Centralized Event Publisher with App1 (using logback)","app":{"name":"otel","service":"postHouse","status":"status name","method":"POST","protocol":"HTTP","resp_time_ms":"250","status_code":"4"},}}"
>
> ]   }

So that I would like to apply Regular Expression for this message to get only the message from `{"type.....`to `"status_code":"4"},}}` and also convert it to JSON format

I have code like this in my .js file

```
Then('extract json from {string}', function(message){
    message = getVal(message, this);
    const getmess = message.match(/{(.*)}/g);
    const messJson = JSON.parse(getmess);
    console.log(messJson);
})
```

But it doesn't work for me

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1

How can I apply this in my code on Javascript? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi ya - Would you please explain why you would like to get only the message from "{"type.....to "status_code":"4"},}}"? If you are planning to get the status code, can't you get the whole message and assert the whole message instead a subset of it?

Comment: @JeromeJosephraj Cause I just want to take only object json from that not include other letter

Comment: Hi Kite - Do you have to? By comparing the entire object, you are not only comparing the status object but the entire message. This way of comparison has an additional advantage of checking all objects in the json so if something else has changed then that would get highlighted as well. By checking only the status object, your scenario might pass, but the message might have an incorrect message somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But keep in mind, that current regex is binded with provided program output syntax. If output will be different in wrapper structure, this regex might not work any more.

```js
// Text from app
const STDOUT = `
    "message": [ "Receiving message: {"type":"CTL","traceId":"f0d11b3dbf27b8fc57ac0e40c4ed9e48","spanId":"a5508acb0926fb1a","id":{"global":"GLkELDUjcRpP4srUt9yngY","caller":null,"local":"GLkELDUisjnGrSK5wKybht"},"eventVersion":"format version","timeStamp":"2021-10-01T14:55:59.8168722+07:00","eventMetadata":{"deleteTimeStamp":null,"ttlSeconds":null,"isFcra":null,"isDppa":true,"isCCPA":true,"globalProductId":null,"globalSubProductId":null,"mbsiProductId":null},"eventBody":{"sys":"otel","msg":"Testing Centralized Event Publisher with App1 (using logback)","app":{"name":"otel","service":"postHouse","status":"status name","method":"POST","protocol":"HTTP","resp_time_ms":"250","status_code":"4"},}}"

    ] }
`;

// Match JSON part string
let JSONstr = /.*\[\s*\"Receiving message:\s*(.*?)\s*\"\s*]\s*}\s*$/.exec(STDOUT)[1];

// Remove trailing comma(s)
JSONstr = JSONstr.replace(/^(.*\")([^\"]+)$/, (s, m1, m2) => `${m1}${m2.replace(/\,/, "")}`);

// Convert to object
const JSONobj = JSON.parse(JSONstr);

// Result
console.log(JSONobj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
/.*?({"type":.*?,"status_code":"\d+"\})/
```

When used in Javascript, the part covered by the parentheses counts as Group 1, i.e.,:

```
const messJson = JSON.parse(message.match(/.*?({"type":.*?,"status_code":"\d+"\})/)[1]);
```

Reference here: https://regexr.com/66mf2

Comment: This show null for me

Comment: If it's null, that means there wasn't a match yet. Is the ending bit of the logs always consistent? i.e., it always ends with `status_code`?